# Creating a library of Protocols and defrecords for use from Java

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, clojure-protocol

At the moment, I have a completely functional Clojure library which is called from Java.

The way I do this : I have a file that uses gen-class to wrap the entire API as static methods of a single class and passes data in and out in the form of IPersistentVector and IPersistentMap.

Now, however, I'm refactoring the library and putting the functionality behind various Protocols.

I have four protocols, lets call them A, B, C and D. And two defrecords, X and Y. X and Y both implement protocols A, B and C. While Y also implements D.

What do I need to do to make these available to Java? Are these automatically available as Interfaces and Classes? Or do I still have to do the equivalent of the gen-class to make them public?

If not, what is the equivalent of the gen-class :methods clause, where I define the Java types for the arguments to the methods?

Does anyone have a simple example of making Protocols and records available to Java?

Answer (score 6):

[**`defprotocol`**](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defprotocol)

Every Clojure protocol is also a Java interface with the same name and methods. If I take an example from [ibm developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-clojure-protocols/), we see that :

```
(ns com.amalgamated)

(defprotocol Fulfillment
  (invoice [this] "Returns an invoice")
  (manifest [this] "Returns a shipping manifest"))
```

Is equivalent to :

```
package com.amalgamated;

public interface Fulfillment {
    public Object invoice();
    public Object manifest();
}
```

[Clojure.org](http://clojure.org/protocols) also has some (rather terse) information on this.

> A Java client looking to participate in the protocol can do so most
>   efficiently by implementing the protocol-generated interface. External
>   implementations of the protocol (which are needed when you want a
>   class or type not in your control to participate in the protocol) can
>   be provided using the extend construct:
>
> ```
> (extend AType   AProtocol   
>  {:foo an-existing-fn
>     :bar (fn [a b] ...)
>     :baz (fn ([a]...) ([a b] ...)...)}   BProtocol
>     {...} ...)
> ```

[**`definterface`**](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/definterface)

If you are aiming at performance, you could consider using `definterface`, which use is similar to the protocols. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914607/how-to-use-definterface-in-clojure) also has details about how to use it :

```
(definterface Foo
  [^int foo [x ^String y]]
  [^void bar [^ints is]])
```

`definterface` seem to be [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124344/clojure-number-crunching-performance) than protocols.

[**`defrecord`**](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord)

Similarly, `record`s (as well as `deftype` and `definterface`)  will generate Java Classes.
Again, [Clojure.org/datatypes](http://clojure.org/datatypes) has useful information (emphasis mine) :

> deftype and **defrecord** dynamically generate compiled bytecode for a
>   **named class** with a set of given fields, and, optionally, **methods for
>   one or more protocols and/or interfaces**. They are suitable for dynamic
>   and interactive development, **need not be AOT compiled**, and can be
>   re-evaluated in the course of a single session. They are similar to
>   defstruct in generating data structures with named fields, but differ
>   from defstruct in that: [...]

So yes if will be available from Java.
Just be careful with naming.

As a side note, you may want to have a look at [calling Clojure from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java).